# Django No handlers could be found for logger "cities"

Tags: django

I'm trying to setup Django-Cities https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities by using the following command:

```
sudo python manage.py cities --force --import=all
```

After around 10 mins the terminal prints:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "cities"
```

Then nothing happens, I wait for hours. I checked the database and no data had been added to the database generated by syncdb.

Some of my settings.... Settings

```
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'

# List of plugins to process data during import
```

CITIES_PLUGINS = [
    'cities.plugin.postal_code_ca.Plugin',  # Canada postal codes need region codes remapped to match geonames
]

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'accounts',
    'userena',
    'guardian',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'events',
    'cities',

    )


# Django-guardian settings

ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.Profile'

# GEOS Library
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
CITIES_POSTAL_CODES = ['GB']


    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'filters': {
            'require_debug_false': {
                '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'mail_admins': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
                'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True,
                },
            }
    }
```

Comment: edit you settings and add a to loggers cities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should output to screen.

```
 LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'filters': {
            'require_debug_false': {
                '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'mail_admins': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
                'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            },
            'console':{
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True,
                },
            'cities': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'INFO'
            },

            }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I can now see the error: _mysql_exceptions.Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xCA\xBCs al...' for column 'name_std' at row 1 thanks

Comment: This is a really old post, but it came in handy! Thank you much!