# django-datables error - No handler could be found?

Tags: django, django-views, django-datatable

I am using the [django-databtables-view](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datatables-view) app, but I get this following error in my console. what am I missing here?

```
No handlers could be found for logger "django_datatables_view.mixins"
```

I included the logging in my settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to your handlers definition

```
   'null': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
     }
```

And this to your loggers

```
'django_datatables_view.mixins': {
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
```

You could also set some other handler that actually logs something, check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530526/django-no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-cities?rq=1)